# How can I create a custom Select All keybinding in Vimperator 3.1?

Tags: vimperator

I just upgraded to Vimperator 3.1.  Previously I used customized key bindings with the Passing Through protocol. It seems the new version accomodates them for pasting and copying, but not selecting all. I don't know how to program the new key bindings because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is no longer Pass Through. Is this still possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this could help:

```
:inoremap <C-a> <Ins><C-a><Ins>
```

via http://code.google.com/p/vimperator-labs/issues/detail?id=578#c3

About *inoremap* - http://vimperator.org/help/vimperator/map.xhtml

Comment: Both links are broken. The remap works though, and I thank you for it :)